# How to get SonarQube results back to CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, bitbucket, sonarqube-scan, aws-codepipeline

I've seen many discussions on-line about Sonar web-hooks to send scan results to Jenkins, but as a CodePipeline acolyte, I could use some basic help with the steps to supply Sonar scan results (e.g., quality-gate pass/fail status) to the pipeline.
Is the Sonar web-hook the right way to go, or is it possible to use Sonar's API to fetch the status of a scan for a given code-project?
Our code is in BitBucket.  I'm working with the AWS admin who will create the CodePipeline that fires when code is attempted to be pushed into the repo.  `sonar-scanner` will be run, and then we'd like the pipeline to stop if the quality does not pass the Quality Gate.

If I would use a Sonar web-hook, I imagine the value for `host` would be, what, the AWS instance running the CodeBuild?

Any pointers, references, examples welcome.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/webhooks/) you can find the provided documentation about when to use the webhook and the payload provided.

Comment: I found Sonar's web-api `http://localhost:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=my-project` allows me to get back the pass/fail status based on the quality gate.   This might be all I need.

Comment: Did you manage to find a working solution? I am looking for the exact same capability. Can you share your findings please? Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesMorin - I've since left that project, sorry, but I think we went with using the API per my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a powershell to use with Azure DevOps, that possible may be migrated to some shell script that runs in the code build activity

https://github.com/michaelcostabr/SonarQubeBuildBreaker